# Why is $\{a^n b^m c^p: n\neq m\} \cup \{a^n b^m c^p: m\neq p\}$ an inherently ambiguous language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, pushdown-automata, ambiguity

I came across a very hard interview question in last month’s Ph.D. entrance exam. It was asking which one of the languages is inherently ambiguous. Short answer says 2). Why is the language in 2) an inherently ambiguous language?

1) $L = \{a^n b^{2n} c: n\geq 0\} \cup \{a^{2n} b^n d: n\geq 0\}$

2) $L = \{a^n b^m c^p: n\neq m\} \cup \{a^n b^m c^p: m\neq p\}$

3) $L = \{a^n b a^{2n}: n \geq 0\} \cup \{a^{2n} b a^n: n\geq 0\}$

4) $L = \{\omega: \omega \in \{a,b\}^*: \omega \text{ does not have substring $baba$}\} \cup \{\omega : \omega \in \{a,b\}^*: \omega \text{ does not have substring $abab$} \}$

Comment: You can immediately rule out 1) and 3) by constructing their unambiguous CFG. The language in 4) is regular (complement and union preserves regularity) and therefore there is an unambiguous regular grammar (which is also context-free). Thus the only remaining option is 2). If you’re sure one of them is inherently ambiguous, you can be sure it is the one in 2).

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understaing. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: Mind what mods and hi-rep users tell you, @MaryamPanahi. I see two of your questions have been closed  Continuing in such a trend could lead to a question ban. You need to have 20 rep to be able to participate in the chat, so for the time being use comments here to try to shortly answer what Raphael asks. When we know what specific problems you have with understanding why $L = \{a^n b^m c^p: n\neq m\} \cup \{a^n b^m c^p: m\neq p\}$ is inherently ambiguous, we will be able improve your question and answer it.

Comment: E.g. do you want to get a proof that that language is inherently ambiguous? Do you know how to prove inherent ambiguity for any other language? Have you tried to read such a proof for another language and failed to understand a step?

Comment: The title of the question is incongruous with your actual desideratum.

Comment: Most likely, the purpose of the question is not to have you prove that case 2) is an inherently ambiguous language, but only to force you to show that the other 3 are not inherently ambiguous (in case that was not clear).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $L_1,L_2$ are two disjoint context-free languages which are not inherently ambiguous, then $L_1 \cup L_2$ is also a context-free language which is not inherently ambiguous. The reason is simple: starting with context-free grammars for $L_1,L_2$ with start symbols $S_1,S_2$ (respectively) and otherwise disjoint non-terminals, you can construct an unambiguous grammar for $L_1 \cup L_2$ by adding a new start symbol $S$ and the productions $S\to S_1|S_2$. This takes care of 1) and 3), once you construct unambiguous grammars for the constituent languages.

As Palec mentions, 4) is regular, and so admits a regular grammar which corresponds to a DFA accepting it. This grammar has as non-terminals the states of the DFA, and productions $A \to aB$ if the DFA moves from $A$ to $B$ upon reading $a$. For each final state $F$ we add a production $F\to\epsilon$, and the start symbol is the start state. This description should make it clear that the grammar is unambiguous.

Intuitively, 2) could be inherently ambiguous since words of the form $a^n b^m c^p$ with $n \neq m \neq p$ could have two different parse trees, corresponding to the two constituent languages. Proving this formally could be tedious. The only method I know consists of coming up with two words $x,y$ that can be pumped to the same word $w$ in such a way that makes it clear that the corresponding parse trees are different. If you want to pursue this further, a good first step will be to read some examples of this method.